# Render Direct2d into existing memory

Tags: directshow, direct2d, wic

I want to use Direct2D in a DirectShow in-place video transform filter to render text and images on top of the video.  To avoid extra copies, I implemented my own IWICBitmap subclass wrapping the media sample buffer and use CreateWicBitmapRenderTarget to make Direct2D write to that memory.  My question is, did I miss a built-in WIC class to wrap existing memory into a bitmap?

Answer (score 1):

IWICImagingFactory has a method that creates an IWICBitmap with a pointer to image data - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee690291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx - but it sounds like that just copies the data from memory to a new buffer. The only other way to create an IWICBitmap is through other IWICImagingFactory methods that look unhelpful, so most likely there's nothing in WIC that does what you want.